# $\mathbb Q$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module is not finitely generated

Tags: ring-theory, modules, finitely-generated

$\mathbb Q$ is obviously a $\mathbb Z$-module, however, it is not finitely generated. I can't figure out why.

If $\mathbb Q$ is finitely generated, then there are $x_i \in \mathbb Q$ such that $\mathbb Q = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb Z x_i$.

I know that I have to construct an element in $\mathbb Q - \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb Z x_i$, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint: Consider a prime not dividing any of the denominators of the $x_i$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the chain of subgroups
$$
\langle 1\rangle\subsetneq
\left<\frac{1}{2}\right>\subsetneq
\left<\frac{1}{4}\right>\subsetneq
\dots\subsetneq
\left<\frac{1}{2^n}\right>\subsetneq
\left<\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right>\subsetneq
\dotsb
$$

---

Alternatively: suppose $x_1,x_2,\dots x_n\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then you can write
$$
x_i=\frac{a_i}{b},\quad i=1,2,\dots,n
$$
for some integers $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b>0$.

Then $1/(2b)\notin\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$, otherwise
$$
\frac{1}{2b}=\frac{a_1c_1+a_2c_1+\dots a_nc_n}{b}
$$
with $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I am still an amateur in this regard. Can you please tell me what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @madmatician $\mathbb{Q}$ is not noetherian, so it's not finitely generated. However, I added a more direct proof.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you had a finite generating set $\frac{a_1}{b_1},...,\frac{a_m}{b_m}$; we can assume all denominators are positive.

Now think about forming a sum of those fractions. You can always group the fractions and rewrite your sum as an integer linear combination
$$n_1 \frac{a_1}{b_1} + ... + n_m \frac{a_m}{b_m} = \frac{n_1 a_1}{b_1} + ... + \frac{n_m a_m}{b_m}
$$
Now ask, what can the denominator of this sum be? It's never going to be larger than the product $b_1 \cdot ... \cdot b_m$. So no matter what sum you form, you're never going to get the rational number
$$\frac{1}{b_1 \cdot ... \cdot b_m+1}
$$